# How to initialize a Google BigQuery Client within a Cloud Function using the JWT of a service account passed by API Gateway to the Cloud Function

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, google-authentication, google-api-gateway

**Goal:**
I have set up a Google API Gateway. The backend for the API is a cloud function (written in python). The cloud function should query data from Google BigQuery (BQ). To do that, I want to create a BQ Client (`google.cloud.bigquery.Client()`). The API should be accessed by different applications using different service accounts. The service accounts have permission to access only specific datasets within my project. Therefore, the service accounts/applications should *only* be able to query the datasets they have the permission for. Therefore, the BQ Client within the cloud function should be initialized with the service account that sends the request to the API.

**What I tried:**
The API is secured with the following OpenAPI definition so that a JWT signed by the service account SA-EMAIL is required to send a request there:

```yaml
securityDefinitions:
  sec-def1:
    authorizationUrl: ""
    flow: "implicit"
    type: "oauth2"
    x-google-issuer: "SA-EMAIL"
    x-google-jwks_uri: "https://www.googleapis.com/robot/v1/metadata/x509/SA-EMAIL"
    x-google-audiences: "SERVICE"
```

For the path that uses my cloud function, I use the following backend configuration:

```yaml
x-google-backend:
  address: https://PROJECT-ID.cloudfunctions.net/CLOUD-FUNCTION
  path_translation: CONSTANT_ADDRESS
```

So in the cloud function itself I get the forwarded JWT as `X-Forwarded-Authorization` and also the already verified base64url encoded JWT payload as `X-Apigateway-Api-Userinfo` from the API Gateway.
I tried to use the JWT from `X-Forwarded-Authorization` to obtain credentials:

```py
bearer_token = request.headers.get('X-Forwarded-Authorization')
token = bearer_token.split(" ")[1]
cred = google.auth.credentials.Credentials(token)
```

At first, this seems to work since `cred.valid` returns `True`, but when trying to create the client with `google.cloud.bigquery.Client(credentials=cred)` it returns the following error in the logs:

```
google.auth.exceptions.RefreshError: The credentials do not contain 
the necessary fields need to refresh the access token. You must 
specify refresh_token, token_uri, client_id, and client_secret.
```

I do not have much experience with auth/oauth at all, but I think I do not have the necessary tokens/attributes the error is saying are missing available in my cloud function.
Also, I am not exactly sure why there is a `RefreshError`, since I don't want to refresh the token (and don't do so explicitly) and just use it again (might be bad practice?).

**Question:**
Is it possible to achieve my goal in the way I have tried or in any other way?

Comment: I looked into some of my old code... I don't remember why, but I used to add "cred.refresh(requests.Request())" after credentials are created. The requests - is "from google.auth.transport import requests". So, all together it looks: "    tgt_credentials = impersonated_credentials.Credentials(
        source_credentials=src_credentials,
        target_principal=<email of the target service account>,
        target_scopes=tgt_scopes,
        lifetime=500)
tgt_credentials.refresh(requests.Request())
"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your goal is to catch the credential that called the API Gateway, and to reuse it in your Cloud Functions to call BigQuery.

Sadly, you can't. Why? Because API Gateway prevent you to achieve that (and it's a good news for security reason). The JWT token is correctly forwarded to your Cloud Functions, but the signature part has been removed (you receive only the header and the body of the JWT token).

The security verification has been done by API Gateway and you have to rely on that authentication.

---

**What's the solution?**

My solution is the following: In the truncated JWT that you receive, you can get the body and get the Service Account email. From there, you can use the Cloud Functions service account, to impersonate the Service Account email that you receive.

Like that, the Cloud Functions service account only needs the permission to impersonate these service account, and you keep the permission provided on the original service account.

I don't see other solutions to solve your issue.

Answer (score 2):

The JWT that you are receiving from API Gateway is not an OAuth Access Token. Therefore the JWT Payload portion is not a credential that you can use for the BigQuery Client authorization.

As **@guillaume blaquiere** pointed out, the Payload contains the email address of an identity. If the identity is a service account, you could implement impersonation of that identity. This could be a good solution if you are using multiple identities with API Gateway. If the identity is a user account, then you would need to implement Domain-Wide Delegation.

I recommend simply using the service account assigned to the Cloud Function with proper roles assigned to initialize the BigQuery client. Provided that API Gateway is providing authorization to reach your Cloud Function, there is no need for the extra layer of impersonation.

Another option is to store the matching service account JSON key file in Secret Manager and pull it when required to create the BigQuery Client.